# Trouble Installing Gitlabhq on Centos but getting rb-fsevent error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos

I need to install Gitlabhq on Centos by assisting this page https://github.com/mattias-ohlsson/gitlab-installer/blob/master/gitlab-install-el6.sh but i am getting rb-fsevent error.

I already installed the latest version of rb-fsevent gem said but i can not execute `bundle install`

```
$gem install fr-fsevent
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.9.3
Done installing documentation for rb-fsevent (0 sec).
1 gem installed
```

But when i run bundle install i am getting this:

```
An error occurred while installing rb-fsevent (0.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rb-fsevent -v '0.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I searched too many things but could not find a good solution.

Comment: Well, the error message tells you: Install by executing `gem install rb-fsevent -v '0.9.2'`, so that the correct version is installed. Currently, you have a newer version installed.

Comment: You right. Thanks. But the main issue is operating system. Centos does not effectively a good host for Gitlabhq. There are too many issue related with gem, bundle and rails as well.